# Semantic UI - Trying to display 10 movies in my IMDB App

Tags: reactjs

I'm building IMDB App with ReactJS for my school project.
The project is in finishing state, however, I'd need to display 10 movies on a search basis.

I've used [semantic-ui](https://react.semantic-ui.com/) here, but somehow my application displays only 8 movies per search.

I've followed some documentation from dev.to, including researching Stackoverflow on this subject, but could hardly fix the code.

Could someone please help me out here? Here's my `MoviesList` component.
Thanks in advance guys!

```js
import React from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { Card, Container } from "semantic-ui-react";
import MovieCover from "./MovieCover";

function MoviesList() {
  const movieList = useSelector((state) => state.movieList);
  const show = useSelector((state) => state.showListScreen);
  const showDetailScreen = useSelector((state) => state.showDetailScreen);
  const movies = movieList[0] || [];

  if (showDetailScreen === true && show === true) {
    return (
      <Card>
        <Card.Group itemsPerRow={10} centered doubling>
          {movies.map((item) => (
            <MovieCover key={item.id} item={item} title={item.l} />
          ))}
        </Card.Group>
      </Card>
    );
  } else if (show === true) {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Card.Group itemsPerRow={5} doubling centered stackable>
          {movies.map((item) => (
            <MovieCover key={item.id} item={item} title={item.l} />
          ))}
        </Card.Group>
      </Container>
    );
  } else return null;
}

export default MoviesList;
```

Comment: Are you definitely getting 10+ results back from the actual search?

Comment: Hi foakesm, I'm only getting 8 results back from the search. I'm thinking that maybe it is due to the IMDB API key I'm using. Is there a chance that could be it?